# AWS S3 and Angular, files are not being updated

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, deployment

For prod I do:

```
ng build --prod
```

and also I've been using:

```
ng build --prod --configuration production
```

(because I have some enviroment vars that are different from prod and dev)

The problem is everytime I run `ng build` the dist files has the same name, like this:

[image]

The same name of each file. So, when I go to my bucket of S3, I delete the previous version of the files, then I upload the new dist ones, but I can't see the changes on my site, because S3 caches my files because has the same name.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Amazon Cloud Front for deployment. Issue is with CloudFront Distribution.
CloudFront store files in cache, that's why you don't see changes instantly.
Here's [a link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) for more details.

And the solution is to change cache settings follow this link
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/prevent-cloudfront-from-caching-files/.

Configuration on the distribution

1. Open the CloudFront console.
2. From your list of CloudFront distributions, choose the distribution that you want to modify.
3. Choose the Behaviors tab.
4. If you already have a cache behavior for the objects that you don't want  CloudFront to cache, select the cache behavior and choose Edit. To create a new cache behavior, choose Create Behavior.
5. In the cache behavior's settings, enter the following to prevent caching:
6. For Object Caching, select Customize.
7. For Minimum TTL, enter 0.
8. For Maximum TTL, enter 0.
9. Choose Create to save the changes that you made.